# Handle Azure instances scale down with node

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a web app over Azure with some scale out rules configured.

What I want to do is performing some internal actions when Azure scales down and therefore an instance goes down.

How can I detect this scaled down using *node.js*? After checkging the documentation I only read a possible *onStop/stopping* events related but using *C#*.

I tried '*SIGINT*', '*SIGTERM*' and '*SIGQUIT*' system signals without success.

Comment: Could you please share the resource you found for C# regarding stopping events? [I only found something related to Cloud Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/the-right-way-to-handle-azure-onstop-events/) and not App Service.

Comment: The main question is if you want to detect this inside the application itself or outside it.

Comment: I want to detect the stopping event from the application itself. This is the resource I found regarding a role instance when is stopped https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.stopping.aspx